# 70-persistent-net.rules file does not exist on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w

I am on a Raspberry Pi Zero W. When I cd to the the /etc/udev/rules.d folder, the only file that exists is "99-com.rules". After a bit of research, I came across only two possible solutions, apt-get install udev (which failed as I was already on the latest version), and to try and run a script, or reboot and get a new 70-persistent-net.rules file, autogenerated by the /lib/udev/rules.d/write_net_rules file. That file was also not present. My only guess was that the solution was a package that I hadn't installed, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)
Presumably you are looking for some reason, but you would be better to ask about your actual problem.

Comment: Well the goal of all of this was to set up my Raspberry Pi 0 Wireless as an access point, just by using the Pi and its own wireless interface (presumably divided into two interfaces, one to connect to the internet and one to act as the access point interface, which involves the 70-persistent-net.rules file). No guide I've found is for the Raspberry Pi 0 Wireless, and no modifications to the instructions that I've made have come close to really functioning. I'm preeeeetty lost about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface naming changed significantly under debian stretch, and your guide is likely for jessie or older. You can find details on how to migrate the older approach, described in the linked article, to the new format under `/usr/share/doc/udev/README.Debian.gz`. In short, you can either create your own interface names with `udev` using the examples shown in the README, or use `systemd.link`.

There is more info specific to the RPi [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191639). Quoting that page:

> In order to enable the ability to assign user-defined names to USB network interfaces, we need to have /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules, as this is the rule set 73-usb-net-by-mac.rules checks against before assigning NAME.
>
> This means that simply linking from
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules to
>   /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules is needed in order to avoid
>   that user-assigned network interface names get ignored any longer.
>
> `sudo ln -s /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`
>
> Reboot. Done.

I have not done this yet myself, but have been reading up on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know where a particular distro packaged file comes from:

```
apt install apt-file
```

You can then use:

```
apt-file search /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

However, if that file, as you hypothesize, was generated by the also missing `/lib/udev/rules.d/write_net_rules`, then it won't be found -- I get nothing on a stock Debian stretch arm system, but something here may be peculiar to Raspbian (or something that disappeared in stretch, aka. v.9, if you are using a new image compared to your other systems).

`apt-file` by default looks for literal matches, but `-x` will do a [pcre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) match, according to which surprisingly few things add to `/etc/udev/rule\.d/.+rules`.  A great many things, though, match `/lib/udev/rules\.d/.+`.  Fed through `| grep write` I get nothing again -- but this may still be a Raspbian peculiarity.

You could try stuff like:

```
apt-file -x search '/lib/udev/rules\.d/70.+'
apt-file -x search '/lib/udev/rules\.d/.+' | grep persistent
```

And see if you find anything.  Debian's [online package search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) gives nothing for `70-persistent-net.rules` and `write_net_rules` in current stable (which, again, is stretch, aka. v.9).

Comment: On tutorials like the following: http://www.0xf8.org/2016/02/using-your-raspberry-pi-zeros-usb-wifi-adapter-as-both-wifi-client-and-access-point/, it used a similar setup, albeit for a Raspberry Pi Zero (not a Zero W), but they used this file. I did searches for both, as you suggested, and found nothing.